# How do I properly encode URLs in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, url, encoding, view

In my database I have URLs starting with `http://SOMEURL` and some are just www.SOMEURL.

in my view, ‚if I just put `<a href="@Model.URL">` it wont work properly.
It adds `http://localhost/SOMEURL` when I try to browse locally.

How do I handle this BASIC functionality in ASP ?

google.com    https://www.google.com

Comment: Please post some data example s for `@Model.URL`

Comment: sample added ddddd

Comment: Is it `google.com` or `https://www.google.com` (the 2nd will work fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for http prefix manually. URLs will be encoded automatically (e.g. replacing special characters) in ASP.NET MVC.

In Razor View (.cshtml; Anywhere on top of file)

```
@functions
{
    public string PrefixUrl(string url)
    {
        return url.StartsWith("http") ? url : string.Format("http://{0}", url);
    }
}
```

I wish we could assume *https* nowadays but probably, using *http* is safer.

Then, in View, use:

```
<div>
    <a href="@PrefixUrl(Model.Url)">Link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant believe there is NO simpler solution. I cant believe I need to deal whether URL starts with HTTP HTTPS WWW or none of that.

Comment: Function `StartsWith("http")` will also cover `https` and render correct url.

Comment: Its very basic. It just says "if your url starts with something http-_ish_, just write it out as is, else assume that the correct prefix is missing and prefix with `http`". You could also change `url.StartsWith("http")` to `url.Contains("://")` to be even more genric with what prefixed URLs have in common